Did I damage my engine?
2010 3.6 Camaro
As I was turning the crankshaft clockwise to set the cam locks the car rolled backwards about 3 feet causing the engine to rotate counterclockwise. I was able to make several revolutions as was able to place cam  locks in place There was no binding or noises to while making revolutions. My blocks had moved causing this to happen. Car was on ramps and car was in 1st gear, e-brake was not set and battery is not disconnected. Is my engine ok from this happening?

The LLT engine in your Camaro is an interference engine which means valves and pistons share the same space, just at different times in the revolution of the engine. This means you could have caused damage. In order to find out for sure, I'd suggest you get your engine back together as you were working on in the first place, then do leak down tests on all of the cylinders. If you find cylinders to be much worse than the others, you've probably done damage. I don't know what the spec is for the engine, but all of the cylinders should be fairly close in a leakdown. If there is damage, then you'll probably need to get it professionally looked at or buy new head(s) to replace the damaged ones.
